# php mysql greater than issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: `users, images`.  The users has a column `paid` which is a digit for how many images they paid to enter into the contest..
images has a column `entered` with a value of 0 for not entered, and 1 for entered. I need the sum of these for each user.

I am trying to query all users who paid for more images than they entered. but it's not working correctly.. heres what prints:

```
bob@example.com        8  2  
jcannon@example.com    3  3  
jrcih@example.com      7  3  
aerwqeerll@example.com 5  1  
ray@example.com        2  3
```

You can see that jcannon@ and ray@ should not be in the list, because paid is not greater than entered

here is the code:

```
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT  *, SUM(images.entered) 
                        FROM users, images 
                        WHERE users.id=images.owner 
                        AND users.paid>'SUM(images.entered)' 
                        GROUP BY users.id  ");

while($sendto=mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
    print $sendto['email']." ".$sendto['paid']. 
          " ".$sendto['SUM(images.entered)']. "<br>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is 'SUM(images.entered)' really quoted? This makes it a string. The > operator will cast it to a number, 0, so everybody who paid something will match. Remove the ' ...

Comment: i get 0 results when i remove the quotes... with the quotes, i get results. it also removes users who paid for 0 and entered 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get rid of the quotation marks, they are for literal strings. Second, you can only compare aggregated values with the [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

```
… WHERE … GROUP BY … HAVING users.paid >= SUM(images.entered) …
```

Also I find it often a lot clearer to use explicit join syntax, instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT  *, SUM(images.entered)
FROM users
INNER JOIN images
ON users.id = images.owner
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING users.paid > SUM(images.entered)
```

Comment: i get 0 results when i remove the quotes... with the quotes, i get results. it also removes users who paid for 0 and entered 0

Comment: Johnny, try greater-than-or-equal (`>=`)

Comment: still no results which is weird, because if i take out ` AND users.paid >= SUM(images.entered)` completely. all of my results print correctly showing the `paid` and `sum(entered)` values

Comment: Johnny, I've updated my answer. The problem was using WHERE vs. HAVING

Comment: Thanks!  that did it.  I will research `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Mysql Having](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

*You can use join, if both table have some column identification

```
$SQL = mysql_query("
SELECT  
*, 
SUM(images.entered) as totalImage,
FROM users
INNER JOIN images on (users.id = images.owner) 
HAVING users.paid >  totalImage
GROUP BY users.id  

");
```